# TeXstudio (2.12.22 ) illegible characters in Control panel for Windows Operation System

Tags: texstudio

Recently, I updated the TeXstudio to the updated version (2.12.22), but only error or illegible characters are shown in the control panels, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: This is not a TeX problem, but a TeXstudio problem. Hence, the font-encoding tag is not correct. I believe TeXstudio might have picked the wrong font for its interface. Try to select the configure TeXStudio options. Second to last menu from the right, first option. On the pop-up window, on the left, 1st option, and on the right, the third box. Select a different font, like MS Sans Serif

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the computer?

Comment: @Mensch That usually works in Windows. That's why it's a punchline in 'The IT Crowd'...

Comment: @phollox You answer is exactly what I desperately needed. Really appreciated. 
How to mark your reply as an answer?

Comment: I'll posted it as an answer. You're welcome. I'm glad I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that after the update, TeXstudio might have picked the wrong font for its interface. Try to select the *Configure TeXStudio* options. It's the Second to last menu from the right, the first option on top. Then, on the pop-up window, on the left panel, select the 1st option, and on the right panel, the third box. There, select a different font, like MS Sans Serif